# How to get the req headers in lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have try to send some data to AWS lambda and add data to database.I know how to get the header if using a local server but I don't know where and how to get the header using AWS. I have tried to find some possible solution but I still dont understand and solve my problem.
My api is something like that:

```
export const delectData = function (accessToken, id) {
  return apiClient.post('end point get from API GATEWAY',
    { tableName: '***',
      id: id },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
      }
    })
```

I am using dynamodb to store my data. And I need to get the headers which is the accesstoken for doing validation. Can someone explain to me how to get the header or how to setup in APIGATE step by step? Since the doc in AWS is very unclear for me...

UPDATE: in my postman, It is :[image][image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your API is not a **Lambda Proxy integration**

1.Go to your method ***Integration Request***

2.Click on ***Mapping Templates***

3.Choose  **When no template matches the request Content-Type header**

3.Click on **application/json** under **Content-Type** -> if does not exist create one.

4.Scroll down and put this template:

```
{
"YourHeader" : "$input.params('YourHeader')",
"body" : $input.json('$')
}
```

5.Redeploy your API.

6.In your Lambda `event.YourHeader`

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201807/discussion-on-answer-by-assael-azran-how-to-get-the-req-headers-in-lambda).